# Instead of using if's, would it better to write an 'equation' that gives you the results you want? (in cases where it makes sense)

Tags: performance, if-statement, coding-style, equation

Instead of:

```
float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(dir, transform.right);
int front = 0;
int back = 0;

if (dotProduct > 0)
{
    // right
    front = 1;
    back = -1;
}
else if (dotProduct < 0)
{
    // left
    front = -1;
    back = 1;
}

Rotate(front, back, angle);
```

Having something like

```
float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(dir, transform.right);
int front = Mathf.Abs(dotProduct) ...;
int back = Mathf.Abs(dotProduct) ...;
Rotate(front, back, angle);
```

Errh, I know `int front = Mathf.Abs(dotProduct) ...;` wont give me either 1 or -1, but I think you understand what I'm thinking, instead of using if's, I'd be "funneling" through an equation that would give me either 1 or -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either expect you to bring real example in question or just don't bother about it unless you want to do something beyond just `if/else`. Your original code is fine. It can be written in shorter way, however. That's using `ternary` operator.

```
float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(dir, transform.right);
int front = dotProduct > 0 ? 1 : -1;
int back = dotProduct < 0 ? 1 : -1;
Rotate(front, back, angle);
```

You see just 4 lines. Almost every programmer knows ternary operator. So this new code does not introduce any complexity for your peers. In fact it's cleaner.

Comment: Not what I asked exactly but I guess it's ontopic of shortening things